# Calling Webservice inside webservice WCF

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, jakarta-ee, wsdl

I'm working on a SOAP project which contains:

- C# client
- C# server (WCF)
- J2EE server (with webservice)

On my **C# Server**, I have my `service` and I'm adding the **J2EE WSDL** to this project to calling a J2EE method.

But I'm still having an issue. Which does not append when I'm calling the WSDL from an console app wjich contains a **MAIN**.

Any clue if there is a restriction or anything else?

the service:

```
public class ClientRequest : IClientRequest
    {
        public STG m_service(STG msg)
        {
            var remoteJavaServer = new ServerServicesClient();
            remoteJavaServer.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Result value for 2 square -> {0}", remoteJavaServer.test(2));


            return msg;
        }

        public int m_square(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("value input = "+i);
            return i*i;
        }
    }
```

the console app :

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new ServerServicesClient();
            client.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("2 -> {0}", client.test(2));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Assuming "the service" is your WCF service, this can work.  Please include an exception or more details about your "issue".

Comment: This is the issue : 
Could not find endpoint element with name '{0}' and contract '{1}' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element.

Comment: Take a look at the config file for your service (web.config if web hosted or someservicehost.exe.config for another sevivce host) and compare it to the app.config in your console project.  The error is a little strange because usually the {0} and {1} are replaced with the service name and the full name of the service interface.  You may want to remove and re-add the Service Reference to make sure there are not any warnings or errors at that time.

Comment: it might be because, the 'service WCF' is actually a library project (wich is hosted on a console app).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, only my 'service' library project was configure with the endpoint to target the WSDL. So, I've add the endpoint to the host console app and now it is working.

Thanks anyway.

Closed.